# Extjs: Sort store based on array order

Tags: arrays, sorting, extjs, extjs4

How can I sort my store based on another array. My array items are

```
  myArray = ["10", "3", "15", "7", "1"]
```

Items in the store have this order already as below. My model has a idParent field which its values are in myArray and I want to sort it based on the array order.

```
  Store before sort: ["item7", "item1","item3", "item10", "item15"] 

  Store after sort:  ["item10", "item3", "item15", "item7", "item1"]
```

I need something like this:

```
 mystore.sort({
                sorterFn: function(?){
                    //sort store based on position of idParent in array
                }
            });
```

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/mda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is just to sort array(Store.data) based on another array.